# Cannot find correct new coordinates of a rotated image in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, coordinates, coordinate-systems, affinetransform, distortion

I'm having some quite of struggling here since last friday...

Let's assume I have a picture like which is a green rectangle of 400x300 pixels, and the position of the top-left corner pixel is of course 0,0, and the bottom right is 399,299.

Now with imagemagick, using either -rotate or -distort SRT or other, I rotate the picture 20° clockwise, and I obtain a new picture that has a total area of 479x419 pixel, with white background at the sides of the rotated green image.

I want to obtain the new coordinates of any given pixel of the old picture.

By using the -affine sx,rx,sx,sy,tx,ty and the common fomulas:
x' = x * sx + y * ry 
y' = x * rx + y * sy

using tx and ty at zero, I do not get the correct new pixel positions that I want.

For example, using the formula above, for instance, the "old" 0,0 pixel is STILL 0,0 in the new picture, but in my mind it should be roughly instead in the position 103,0.
In my mind, the "new" 0,0 should be the top-left corner of the new picture (white pixel), and the "old" 399,299 pixel (bottom right of the green picture) should be now roughly 375,418.

HOW do I get such new information for any given pixel starting from the location information of the old image pixel?

Thanks!!

Comment: When you rotate the image, the pixels will not, in general, end up directly at a location in the grid of pixels that are the new image. So, your transformation will either be choosing the nearest neighbour pixel, or maybe interpolating in one or more directions to "guesstimate" a suitable value. What I am is saying is that the new pixels may not match, one-to-one, the old pixels.